# How to store Integer input from the console to a variable

Tags: assembly, raspberry-pi, arm

I am taking an ARM assembly course in college, and have been working ahead to try and learn as much as possible about how to use the language. We are using the Raspberry Pi with the Raspbian operating system.

I have been trying to make a simple program that loops to whatever number the user enters. Everything works fine when I compare my counter `R3` to a literal number like `#4`. But when I compare the counter to `R4` where the user input is stored it does not work properly. It will either loop once, or many times depending on what all I change in the program, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Note: I know that it's possible to use the C function `scanf()`, but I would only like the assembly solution. I have searched on google, this website, and referenced my textbooks but haven't found a clear answer.

I thought that the problem may have been that the ascii value was being stored instead of an integer, but when I tried to convert the value it didn't change anything. Anyways, here's the code and thank you all for your time!

```
.section .data

message:
    .ascii "Hello, World!\n"
    len = .-message

prompt:
    .ascii "Enter a number:\n"
    promptLen = .-prompt



.section .text

.balign 4 
count: .word 0



/*!!! Program Start !!!*/
.global main
main:

_prompt1:
    MOV R7, #4           @ Syscall for write
    MOV R0, #1           @ Write to console
    LDR R2, =promptLen  @ Buffer size 
    LDR R1, =prompt      @ Store string address in r1
    SWI 0               


_getInput:
    MOV R7, #3          @ Syscall for read
    MOV R0, #0          @ Read from keyboard
    MOV R2, #1          @ Buffer size
    LDR R1, =count      @ Store input to count var
    LDR R1, [R1]
    SWI 0

    MOV R4, R1          @ Store integer in R4


    MOV R3, #0          @ Start counter at 0
_loop:
    ADD R3, R3, #1      @ Increment counter


_printString:
    MOV R7, #4          @ Syscall for write
    MOV R0, #1          @ Write to console
    LDR R2, =len        @ Store message len in r2
    LDR R1, =message    @ Store message in r1
    SWI 0               


_checkCounter:
    CMP R3, R4         @ Check counter against user input
    BLT _loop          @ If counter <= count jump to loop


_exit:
    MOV R7, #1          @ Syscall for exit
    SWI 0               @ Return control to console

.end
```

Changes made to getInput:

```
_getInput:
    MOV R7, #3          @ Syscall for read
    MOV R0, #0          @ Read from keyboard
    MOV R2, #1          @ Buffer size
    LDRB R1, =count     @ Store input to count var
    SWI 0

    LDRB R4, [R1]
    SUB R4, R4, #48
```

Comment: The `LDR R1, [R1]` before the `swi` is wrong, delete it as you need to pass the address. It's only after the read that you want to load from memory and that should be a single byte, e.g. `ldrb r4, [r1]`. Also you need to convert from ascii so `sub r4, r4, #48`.

Comment: Use the [edit link](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59952244/edit) to update your question.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I made the changes you suggested, but it still only loops one time. I'll keep working on it.

Comment: The `LDR R1, =count` was fine you should not have changed that one to `LDRB`.

Comment: Yeah I wasn't sure so I tried it both ways. I'm not sure what's going on, my professor was able to get it working using `scanf()` but I'm trying to stay away from that so I can learn.

Comment: Also your `count` should be in `.data` not `.text` as that is likely read-only and your `read()` will just return `-EFAULT`. With that it works fine here.

Comment: Hey, thanks dude! That's what it was, along with the other errors you pointed out.